# Node/Express. Changing HTML/CSS based on query

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I've been stuck on this for a day and I need help figuring this out. I want it to make sure when a query is called to the node/express server that I can respond when the question page is reuploaded. I want to be able to select the header class div and change the image and text in "question.html". What's the least stress filled way to do this? If I can use jQuery then how can I set it up in Node?

```
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var path = require('path');

// Config body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/question'));
});

var questions = {
  "/?v=5": {
    title: "Awesome!"
    smile: 

  }
  "/?v=4": {
    title: "Great!"
    smile: 

  }
  "/?v=3": {
    title: "OK"
    smile: 

  }
  "/?v=2": {
    title: "Mmmmh..."
    smile: 

  }
  "/?v=1": {
    title: "Oops"
    smile: 

  }

}


app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you want do DOM manipulation to that HTML file on the server then take a look at [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Comment: What exactly you want to do? If is make a request to node with jquery, you can use jquery ajax

Comment: I want to be able to use a click event and based on which button they press the page will load based on a query.